# Codeigniter route expression

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I am trying to dynamically change the routes depending on the user-role. So I have a cache routes.php which I write to when the user logs in. Anyway, I need some url's not to be rerouted:

For now I have:  `$route['(:any)']='CA/$1';` which works fine on any url.

I need all the URI's that start with `auth` or `rest` to be left aside as the first one is the login controller and the second one is the subfolder with controllers used by JQgrids. I have tried this but with no result:

```
$route['^(?!auth|rest).*'] = "CA/$1";
```

Edit: 
@Vlakarados

Your routes are currently working but I have the following problem:

My `routes.php` looks like this:

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['default_controller'] = "auth";

include_once(APPPATH."cache/routes.php");
```

In the Auth controller I do the following:

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {
    function Auth() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index()
    {
        if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
        {
            $this->__checkRoles();
        }
        else
        {
                        //render the form
            }
    }

    function logout()
    {
        session_start();
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        $logout = $this->ion_auth->logout();
        redirect('auth');
    }
    function __checkRoles()
    {

        $role=$this->ion_auth->get_group();
        $this->save_routes($role);
        switch ($role) {

            case 'CA':
                redirect(base_url()); //this is how I'm redirecting now, because it will route to base_url()/CA (but it won't because first it will route to default_controller which is 'Auth'
                break;
            case 'CD':
                redirect(base_url().'CD'); //this is how I used to redirect,
                break;
            case 'DV':
                redirect(base_url().'DV');
                break;
            case 'AC':
                redirect(base_url().'AC');
                break;

            case 'Admin':
                redirect(base_url().'Admin');
                break;
            default:
                show_404();
                break;
        }
    }
    public function save_routes($controller=null)
    {
            $output="<?php ";
            $output.="\$route['auth']='auth';";     
            $output.="\$route['rest']='rest';";
            $output.="\$route['(:any)']='".$controller."/$1';";

            $this->load->helper('file');
            write_file(APPPATH . "cache/routes.php", $output);
            $string = read_file('./path/to/file.php');
    }
}
```

**Solved:**

I've worked this around by not redirecting to base_url() and expecting `base_url().'/CA'` which of course led to `base_url().'/CA/index'` but directly redirecting to `base_url().'/index'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$route['auth']='auth';
$route['auth/(:any)']='auth/$1';
$route['rest']='rest';
$route['rest/(:any)']='rest/$1';

$route['(:any)']='CA/$1';
```

The routes that come first have the topmost priority

Comment: Where exactly? See where you are being sent and tell us

Comment: Well now after the routes are written, I redirect to base_url() and expect to go to base_url('CA') but it tries to go to the default_controller which is 'auth'

Comment: I fact I need that this rule (if added) to be more powerfull then the default controller and it's not, even though I place it before the default controller.